# Guava Collections filter

Tags: java, guava

I am just starting with Guava collections and am trying to write a predicate for a list. I am using Guava 11 since I am on java 5.

Here is my first effort....

```
public abstract class StatusBean {
    public enum Status {GREEN, AMBER, RED, BLUE};
}

public class RegisterReplicationSynchTime {
    private Status status = null;
    public Status getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(Status status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}

public class RegisterReplicationSynchTime {

    public void doFilter() {

        List<RegisterReplicationSynchTime> registerReplicationSynchTimes = dao.getMyList();

        Predicate<StatusBean.Status> predicate = new Predicate<StatusBean.Status>() {                   
            public boolean apply(StatusBean.Status status) {
                return status != StatusBean.Status.GREEN;                       
            }
        };
        // !!!! COMPILER DOES NOT LIKE THIS LINE!!!!!!
        Collections2.filter(registerReplicationSynchTimes, predicate); 
    }
}
```

The compiler does not like the call I am making to filter and it is giving me an error as per below.

```
The method filter (Collection<E>,<Predicate<? super E>) in the type
Collections 2 is not applicable for the arguements
(List<RegisterReplicationSynchTime>,Predicate<StatusBean.Status>)
```

I am not sure what I need to do to get it right. Can someone please give me a hand?

Comment: Java 5?  We're up to JDK 8 now.    Do yourself a favor and upgrade immediately.

Comment: Java 9 in Early Access.

Comment: @duffymo Pretty sure, if this were code was running on a server, it would be a major security risk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message tells you, there is a mismatch between the type of elements in your `List` (`RegisterReplicationSynchTime`) and the elements processed by the predicate (`StatusBean.Status`).

Perhaps you want to change your code to filter a `List<StatusBean.Status>`?